# ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification notification

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

How to flush the cached assets library information after recieving the ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification notification? I am not getting how to empty the cached assets library. I tried to release and recreate the library, but it is still giving the cached values only. Please help if anyone knows how to empty the cached values.

Thanks,
Manjunath

Answer (score 0):

1. I use a NSMutableArray class to store the assets, it always is used as tableview's data source
2. When you receive the notification, you need to reset the assets and call the tableview's reloaddate function